# Let $X$ be an infinite set with a topology $T$, such that every infinite subset of $X$ is closed. Prove that $T$ is the discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be an infinite set with a topology $T$, such that every infinite subset of $X$ is closed. Prove that $T$ is the discrete topology.

I have somewhat of an answer but I don't think it's enough to prove it, especially with respect to the subsets being infinite.

Let $S$ be contained in $X$, then $X \setminus S$ is also contained in $X$. Therefore we can say that $X \setminus S$ is closed, therefore $S$ is open for any $S$ contained in $X$. Hence $T$ is the discrete topology.

Thanks

Comment: "Therefore we can say that $X \setminus S$ is closed" why?

Comment: You can say that $X\setminus S$ is closed only in the case where $X\setminus S$ is finite, which doesn't have to happen.

Comment: @nik : This is not the same problem, the question you linked says that every infinite subset of $X$ is -open-, not closed.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: You're right, my apologies.

Answer (score 5):

If $X$ is infinite, let $x \in X$ ; it follows that since $\{x\}$ is finite, $X \backslash \{x\}$ is infinite, hence closed. Therefore, for any subset $S \subseteq X$, 
$$
S = \bigcup_{x \in S} \{x\}
$$
is a union of open sets, thus open. This means $T$ is all subsets of $X$. You have the discrete topology.

Hope that helps,

Comment: But how do we know that $\{x\} \in \tau$?

Comment: @zermelovac : I have proven that. I have shown that $X \backslash \{x\}$ is infinite, hence closed, so that $\{x\}$ is open.

Comment: So if $\{x \}$ is open, then $\{x \}\in T$.

I know that:

$(X,\tau)$ discrete topology $\Leftrightarrow$ $(\forall x \in X)\; \{x\}\in \tau$.

Comment: Can you explain your conclusion that $T$ is all subsets of $X$. Maybe then, I will understand.

Comment: @zermelovac : Any subset is the union of its singleton subsets and arbitrary unions of open subsets are open. Therefore if singletons are open, any subset of $X$ is open.

Comment: I have understood that. The question a have is:

If all the subsets of $X$ are open, then $\tau$ is the discrete topology?

Comment: Is it possible to use AofC since X is infinite

Comment: @Eudoxus Why would you want to use the axiom of choice here? I didn't need it.

Comment: X is infinite set,and has infinite subset

Comment: @Eudoxus: It's not because you work with infinite sets that you need the axiom of choice. The axiom of choice says that if you have a collection of sets (indexed by a set), you can pick one element in each set of your collection. In other words, if {X_i}_{i in I} is a set, then the product prod_{i in I} X_i is not empty, so you get an I-tuple of elements of each X_i. But here we don't need such a thing. It is true by the axiom of extensionality that the two sets above are equal (they contain the same elements) and since the union on the right is a union of open sets, S is open.

Comment: Did you get the email I sent you about learning different math topics @PatrickDaSilva

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is infinite so it is closed so $\emptyset = X^c$ is open. $\boxed{\emptyset \in T}$

$X\setminus\{x\}$ is infinite so $\{x\}$ is open. $\boxed{\forall x \in X,\{x\}\in T}$

And for $A \subseteq X$ where $A\not= \emptyset$, $A=\bigcup\limits_{x\in A}\{x\}$. So $\boxed{\mathcal P(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}\subseteq T}$

So $\boxed{T=\mathcal P(X)}$

Comment: You already know that $T$ is a topology, thus it is clear that $\varnothing \in T$.

Comment: @xaviermo2 But how do we know that $\{x\} \in T$?

Comment: @zermelovac $T$ is the set of open sets. Since $\{x\}$ is finite and $X$ is infinite, $X\setminus \{x\}$ is infinite and is therefore closed. And saying that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is closed is the same thing as saying that $\{x\}$ is open. So $\{x\}\in T$.

Answer (score -1):

Every infinite subset of X closed means every finite subset of X is open. In particular, the singleton sets {x} for all x in X are open. This is sufficient to conclude that T is discrete!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't go back to 5-year-old questions with multiple good answers and provide another answer that doesn't add anything new.